# Why am I unable to ping another computer in the same local network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, ping

Everything was Ok until We have changed our modem (the same type as last one huawei HG532e).  I have a valid IP configuration on my laptop but I cant ping anything on my local network or anything on my remote networks.  I have a stable connection to the internet.  I can get to any website just fine. No computer can ping another one. we are all connected through wifi. 
any idea please

Comment: Maybe ICMP is blocked by modem's firewall? or your WiFi segment is set as isolated (block interconnection between segment nodes)? Can you ping your modem addresses (internal, external)?

Comment: the firewall is set to off in the modem
i can ping to the modem using 192.168.1.1

Comment: When you ping other computers on the local network, does an arp entry for that IP appear in your arp table? If so, ICMP is probably blocked. If not, it is something lower.

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same problem yesterday, after a change on my router too, in Windows 10. After that, I wan unable to ping or log into the minecraft instance on another PC in same network.

This happened because Windows detect the change and assign another network config, with the "public" profile. Just change the profile to "private". Click in network icon, select the wired network, select again and change to "private" in both computers.